# Optimal match all records within date range, large mongo data set

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

- MongoDB 5
- 9 million records in a collection
- sparse index on a `createdAt` field.
- Aggregation match to find all records created before a certain date
- Issue is, the index is hit, but the IXSCAN takes about 60 seconds.

What can be done to speed this up?

```
const result = await collection.aggregate([{ $match: { createdAt: { $lte: /* SOME DATE */ } } }]);
```

Comment: How many documents do match the condition? If your aggregation pipeline fetches millions of documents, then it simply takes some time to transfer them.

Comment: And what portion of the collection overall does the matching results represent? The larger portion of the full collection it is, the less beneficial indexes will be compared to just doing a full collection scan